# Why I've got Fatal error of undefined validation function in my form?

Tags: 7, forms

I get the error in below code, it is strange, why it occurred?

In `hook_menu`

```
$items['share/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('ym_alter_sharing_content'),
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

and:

```
function ym_alter_sharing_content($form, $form_state) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $nid=arg(1);
  $form = node_add('share');

  //$form['field_nid']['und'][0]['value']['#value']=$nid;
  //$form['#submit'][]='ym_alter_sharing_submit';
  //form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  return $form;
}
```

but it return me:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_form_validate()

Where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include node.pages.inc from node module? that's where [`node_form_validate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_validate/7) is defined.

Comment: @Mołot I include it `module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');`

Comment: It's because you're trying to include another form into your existing form. You need to use `hook_form_alter()`. I'm sure you know that already though

Comment: @Clive how I should do it? I want in callback function I have add share content type

Comment: You haven't declared a callback function, you've declared a _form_ and are using `drupal_get_form()` as your callback. Change your callback to `ym_alter_sharing_content()` and return `node_add('share');` or something like that

Comment: @Clive Today I have a bad day, I am sad, great,thank you very much Master Clive :). I found my mistake

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change page callback form drupal_get_form to function, because if you use `drupal_get_form` in call back it return form and in your function you create another form, it means form in form and make conflict.

```
$items['share/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'ym_alter_sharing_content',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Comment: Always use `form_load_include()` in forms. Otherwise you will not load your files when form is cached.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error, because of missing `&`.

When you're using `form_load_include()` in [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), make sure you're following the right API syntax which is:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
```

otherwise [`form_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_load_include/7) can't perform alterations of your current state of the form (`$form_state`).